Question about filtered colimits of diagrams of open/closed maps between topological spaces
Let $X_i$ be a filtered diagram of topological spaces. I am interested in when the canonical maps $f_i:X_i\rightarrow \text{colim } X_i$ are open/closed. It is pretty easy to show that if the transition maps $t_{i,j}:X_i\rightarrow X_j$ are open/closed and injective, then the canonical maps are open/closed.
I have the following proof

Let $Z\subset X_i$ be closed. We have to show that $f_iZ$ is closed. By definition of the topology on the colimit $f_iZ$ is closed if and only if $f^{-1}_jf_iU$ is closed in $X_j$ for all $j$. We can restrict to all $j>i$, since this is a filtered colimit. For $j>i$ we can write $f_i = f_j\circ t_{i,j}$. So $f_iZ$ is closed if and only if $f_j^{-1}f_jt_{i,j}Z$. It is a set theoretical property of colimits that if all the transition maps of a diagram are injective that then the canonical maps are injective. So all the $f_j$ are injective. It follows that $f_j^{-1}f_jt_{i,j}Z= t_{i,j}Z$ is closed and hence $f_iZ$ is closed.

However I am interested in such diagrams specifically do not have injective transition maps. I can only assume that in general it is not the case that if the transition maps are open/closed that then the canonical maps are open/closed. I have not been able to prove such statement (even with extra assumptions), and I also have not been able to find a counter example.
I think that local compactness of the spaces might play a role (specifically for the closed case).
Does anyone know anything about this. I am mainly interested in the closed case, but any insights are very welcome.
